# Water prefab in unity is invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I've imported standard assets package from asset store but the water prefab of it is not working for some reason [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The water script has compiler errors. You have to fix it, since it controls the properties of the used shader.

Answer (score 0):

The water script had some GUI text error which was obsolete in unity so replace it with UnityEngine.UI.Text and it'll solve the problem and don't forget to include using UnityEngine.UI; in the header of course